# TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

The following line of code from my Cloud Function was working fine last year.

`event.data.adminRef.update({fromDB:1})`

After a year of inactivity, I redeployed my function today (after updating everything) and I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined`

So, I changed it to this:
`change.adminRef.update({fromDB:1})`

But, I still get the same error.

What has changed since last year? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add to your question the **entire** code of your Cloud Function, as well as the version of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions (look for `"firebase-functions"` in the `package.json` file)

Comment: I'd like to delete this question. I can't delete it from the app.

Answer (score 2):

The `adminRef` property was present in the beta version of the `firebase-functions` library, but it was removed in the 1.0 version. You can now just use the `ref` property to get the same behavior.

See the section [`adminRef` replaced by `ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#adminref_replaced_by_ref) in the documentation on [upgrading from beta to version 1.0 or higher](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff). That also shows other things that have changed, and which you may have to update in your code.